# Codeigniter. How to check for duplicates in nested array and update it if duplicates exist?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

How to check if nested array contains duplicates? if it does contain duplicate then how to update it?

**Example**

```
Array
(

[0] => Array
    (
        [pre_order_id] => 10
        [product_id] => 1
        [product_quantity] => 11
        [product_unit_id] => 2
        [storage_location_id] => 1
        [price] => 1111
    )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pre_order_id] => 10
            [product_id] => 1
            [product_quantity] => 11
            [product_unit_id] => 2
            [storage_location_id] => 1
            [price] => 1111
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pre_order_id] => 10
            [product_id] => 3
            [product_quantity] => 11
            [product_unit_id] => 2
            [storage_location_id] => 1
            [price] => 1111
        )
)
```

Here **`product_id`** is duplicated on two occasions .i want to keep only one and also update the quantity of it by adding the `product_quantity` of the other array which will be discarded.

I have tried this

```
  // $input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $data_array)));
```

But it only removes duplicates not update .

Comment: well if you make the array index based off the pre_order_id and not just 0,1,2,etc. then duplicates will be overwritten with themselves thus fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this in pure PHP you can use something like this:

```
function cleanDuplicates($aInput) {
    $outPutArray = array();
    foreach($aInput as $element) {
        if(!isset($outPutArray[$element["product_id"]])) {
            $outPutArray[$element["product_id"]] = $element;
        }
        else {
            $outPutArray[$element["product_id"]]["product_quantity"] += $element["product_quantity"];
        }
    }

    return $outPutArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After removing duplicates.You have to use `$this->db->update_batch()` for updating multidimensional array. Like this..

```
$this->db->update_batch('table_name',$input,$product_id);
```

For more see [Codeigniter Query Builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)